# Save temporarily-shareable private data using Quorum

Tags: quorum, privacy

Can we use Quorum (or any other Ethererum variation) to save private data that can be shared with other parties for a temp period?

The use case is that: A patient can share his medical data that is related only to a specific category (radiology, dental, etc..). This is can last for a configurable time (ex. the doctor can see the data for the next 10 days only). And the doctor can see the history for a chosen period (ex. 1 year back only).

(Note: The question is about saving and sharing the full data, not only the hash of the record.)

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy contracts and kill/selfdestruct them at some later point. to problem is, there is no way of preventing anyone synced with the chain from accessing it. The private state tries in Quorum exist only between two parties, an API could grant other parties access.

Comment: So, you think that there is no way to save and share the data according to the suggested case, as of current Quorum and Ethereum implementation. I think there could be some way. For that, I will leave the question as unanswered for a while. Thanks,

Comment: There is no need for that. Blockchains are a distributed ledger, which live from the distribution of transaction data. there is no way to keep things private, this contradicts core principles of blockchain technology. Quorum solved this with verifiable p2p private state tries, but those aren't accessible to thrid party.